# Citrus Tree Identification

Tags: identification, citrus

My father grew several dwarf limes in Southern California (about 2-3 feet high) that I remember distinctly from my youth. He called them "beer limes" or at least that was the name in my memory. I have found Bearss limes, but they don't look anything like these, so I think it was misidentification.

Sorry, I don't have photos. These were orange fruit with extreme baggy skin, even more than a satsuma, but with a distinct lime-y sour flavor. The Rangpur is the closest I can find, but they don't seem baggy at all.

Any help identifying these trees would be appreciated. Or just let me know I am nuts.

Comment: I'd guess they were "beer limes" in the sense of sticking a slice in your bottle of Corona Beer - or at least your Dad's bottle of Corona Beer...

Answer (score 2):

There are a lot of sour, baggy, orange citrus fruit that can grow in Northern California.  Have you tried looking through some pictures of citrus fruits and see if any match your memory?  [Here's a nice list on wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_citrus_fruits) to start.  Pictures of citrus fruits make pleasant browsing too.

Once you have a better idea of a fruit phenotype, I think the trees being only 2-3 feet tall and productive would really narrow it down.

Comment: I will throw some WAGs out anyway.  Volkamer lemon, kobayashi mikan, or bitter orange